# Linq To Sql Join With Dynamically Structured List

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a Generic Collection List which dynamically selects its columns via the Entity Framework 6.0, using the Dynamic Linq Library.

```
var AnonymousList = context.Table.Select("new (FIELD_1, FIELD_2)")
```

My current concern is when joining the dynamically structured list with another list, because
in the join clause, naturally I am unable to reference the columns of the dynamically structured list.

```
List<CreatedDTO> Holder = from dynamictable in AnonymousList join table2 in context.Table2 on new { dynamictable.FIELD_1 } equals new { table2.FIELD_1 }
```

I have thought of an alternative which is to first get the data from the table and initialize it in another DTO, then dynamically select the column but that hit a wall too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dyanmic join by string type like below:

```
var Holder = AnonymousList.Join(table2,"it.FIELD_1","FIELD_1","new (outer.FIELD_1, outer.FIELD_2)");
```

e.g : northwind dynamic join order and employee
[image]

Comment: Hi Wei Han, thanks for your the response. I tried your code but if my AnonymousList is dynamically structured, there will not be a join extension if utilizing the lambda code you have shared.